# How to recover forecast in original scale from log return regression?

Tags: regression, time-series

I am trying to use a log return model to forecast time series data. I'm a bit confused on how to take the output of the log return regression & convert it into the original scale? For instance:

```
model <- lm(log.diff.data ~ seasonal.var + another.var, data = my.data)
forecast.model <- predict(model, newdata = my.new.data)
```

The log return data was given to me, and all entries (including the first row) have a value.

I know that for log models, all I have to do is simply exponentiate the regression output to recover the forecast values in the original scales. But I'm not sure how to recover from log return. Do we add the previous log value to the regression output (but if we do this, what would we do for the first entry, which has not previous log value?)

Any input would be greatly appreciated!